# Q: DocuSign C# API - Send dynamic Recipient email

Tags: docusignapi

Full transparency, I'm not a web or C# Dev but I inherited a project that is about 90% complete and I'm stuck.

We have a web app that successfully API's the correct data to fields mapped in a DocuSign template but I can't seem to figure out how...or where...to send the person who is filling out data on our web app an email with the DocuSign document.

When the user is finished entering data on our site we redirect to DocuSign successfully, the data is populated as expected and the Sign process completes as expected but the email only comes to the address specified in the DocuSign template under "Add Recipients To Envelope".

Ive looked through some of the DocuSign How To's and any changes I make to the .CS for the DocusignWrapper or RecipientDetails doesnt seem to make any difference.

Hardcoding the email wont work for us since multiple people will be entering data and sending it to the template - so this snip doesnt work for our solution:

```
"recipients": {
"signers": [
    {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "email": "johnsemail@outlook.com",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "routingOrder": "1",
    },
    {
        "name": "Jane Smith",
        "email": "janesemail@outlook.com",
        "recipientId": "2",
        "routingOrder": "2",
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 type of recipients for templates:

1. The "hardcoded" ones that have specified name/email.
2. Placeholders which only have a role name and email/name would be filled in real-time when envelope is created.

You need to modify your original template to use the latter type. This would allow your API to create the envelope from the template and change the recipients only at that point.

Hope this help.